# WPF Method reused on multiple pages - should I use static class or singleton?

Tags: c#

I was reading difference between singleton and static class, but only thing I found out different is that singleton gives you state, can implement interfaces and derive, while static class doesn't have these things. I don't(probably won't) need implementing interfaces or deriving from classes, so I think static class is right thing to do. But I would like to know more about this object state vs static class stateless thing. How would you define the state of the object? Is state meant to be reusable for events in 1 WPF page? This might be a stupid question, but I never followed theory, I just coded things to work :) That's why I am learning them now.

Back to topic.
I have 1 method, that animates label, which is used on different labels across different WPF pages:

```
    private void SetUpAnimation()
    {
        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        doubleAnimation.From = -LabelNameSong.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.To = CanMain.ActualWidth;
        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:10"));
        LabelNameSong.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
    }
```

Since I don't want to copy paste this on every single page, I was thinking to create helper class, static class or utility class(which are the same as I understand) to have this method, which I would call wherever I need(passing the right label as parameter of course).

Some advice appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static class is a class where the methods are all static, and the methods belong to the **class** rather than an **object** created from the class.  A static class is generally used when you don't need an object to hold values and modify them later, but instead expect the values to be passed in and only want the method to perform calculations or operations that are always the same.

a singleton is a design pattern whereby a normal class has a single **object** created, and that object is re-used.  A singleton may have values it handles, but because the object is only ever created once, every other object to interact with the singleton will draw from the same values.  Singletons are useful if you have values that may need to change over the life of the application but that need to be shared, or if you have methods which require values to be stored and retrieved later.

Comment: Thank you sir for deep explanation. Now I understand the difference. Just one thing. You said every object interacts with the singleton will draw from the same values. So once you initialize singleton, it works as a global class for application?

Comment: Yes - there is only one instance of each singleton class within an AppDomain. In practice, for all cases where you aren't fiddling with AppDomains, this means that a singleton instance is unique within an application.

Comment: Once you create a Singleton object, the object is global to the application, assuming that you have a reference to the object either stored or passed around.  Singleton objects are deceptively tough to manage effectively without some sort of Dependency Injection framework (popular DI containers for .Net include ninject, StructureMap, CastleWindsor)

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the static, because there is no interaction between the animation of different labels.

Comment: Thank you sir. Will go with static.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, state is data that is stored between multiple method calls. So for something that does not need to store anything and return to it later, just use a static method. That would be my recommendation here.

State encapsulated in a class is particularly useful when you want to control how that state is accessed, as you can restrict it to the methods of the class, which you control. This helps to keep the state tidy and easy to manage, since you can easily see what code relates to it.

Comment: Thank you sir for state explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply

Static class if methods do not access global variables in the class

Singleton if you have global variables such as a list

Comment: I disagree. Global variables can be static and accessed with static methods. Singletons have other advantages but they are not the only way to implement global state.

Comment: Your point is invalid. That is the definition of the Singleton pattern. And if you have static variables your design is wrong

Comment: The only static variable would be an instance of a singleton.

Comment: Obviously in this case.

Comment: @MarkHomer Your answer makes it look like singletons are the either the only way to implement global state, or always the preferable way.  Most of the time singletons will be a better design than global static variables, but actually many of the problems associated with global state are common to both approaches. See https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/avoid-global-variables-environment-variables-and-singletons/. It is too sweeping to say that a design is wrong because it uses a global variable instead of a singleton. It is more likely that both are wrong.

Comment: @StephenHewlett  Singleton is an accepted design pattern, global static variables can get you in a real mess and lead to difficult to track bugs. I accept Singleton is not the only way but singletons have a place and are relatively easy to maintain.